# How to find the factors whose sum is minimum

Tags: factoring

Lets take a number 108.
How to find **natural numbers** a and b such that ab=108
but there sum should be minimum.
Please show the solution for number 108.

Comment: Can you solve the problem for _real_ numbers $a,b$ with $ab = 108$? Can you infer the principle of the solution for integers from that?

Comment: If we were minimizing over the **reals** the answer would be $a=b=\sqrt{108}$. For integers, pick a factor $a$ as close to $\sqrt{108}\approx 10.4$ as you can. Answer is clear.

Comment: I think that root 108 would give me number whose sum(with itself) would be smallest,right? but I want natural numbers

Comment: Well, the nearest factor to $\sqrt{108}$ is $9$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how you reached 9?indeed 9 plus 12 give lowest sum

Comment: Started to count downward from $10$ until I bumped into a factor. Didn't take long!

Comment: @AndréNicolas how do you know that it will give the smallest sum?I think that  roots gives you minumum sum but any theory for this?Or just observation

Comment: Yes, there is general theory that minimum sum for given product $P$ is reached at $a=b=\sqrt{P}$. Easy calculus, or AM/GM, or transform to the equivalent problem of maximizing product for given sum, which comes down to the behaviour of a quadratic. Now for finding the actual integers, if the product were $100$ digits long, we would want to do the testing efficiently. I don't know of a good algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the AM-GM inequality we then have:

$$\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$$

$$\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{108} = 6\sqrt{3}$$

From the property of AM-GM we know that the equality will hold iff $a=b$. So we get that $a=b=6\sqrt{3} \approx 10.3923048454132638$

You can think of this like the minima of the function $f(a,b) = a+b$ under constrain $g(a,b) = ab - 108 = 0$. So from this and from the fact that the square is the rectangle with smallest perimetar for given area, we conclude that the more "square-shaped" the rectangle is the more smaller the sum $a+b$ will be. (To understand even better, let $a$ be one side of the rectangle and $b$ be the second with area $108$).

So we need to find the greates divisor of 108 smaller than $6\sqrt{3}$ and the smallest divisor greater $6\sqrt{3}$ and add them.

The first one is $12$ and the second is $9$. So the minimal sum is $21$. To get it even better write the divisors of $108$ in ascending order and you can check that the product of the first and the last one will be $108$. The product of the second and second last divisor will be $108$ and so on.

Comment: plz explain "So we need to find the greates divisor of 108 smaller than 63√ and the smallest divisor greater 63√ and add them." Greatest divisor of 108 smaller than 63√ is 6(but yours is 12)? and smallest divisor greater than 63√  is 9?

Comment: As I've posted $6\sqrt{3} \approx 10.39$ so the smallest divisor bigger than $6\sqrt{3}$ is 12, while the the greatest divisor smaller that $6\sqrt{3}$ is 9. In other words:

$$9 \le 6\sqrt{3} \le 12$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming real $a,b>0$

$$a+b=a+\frac{108}a=\left(\sqrt a-\sqrt{\frac{108}a}\right)^2+2\sqrt{a\cdot\frac{108}a}\ge2\sqrt{a\cdot\frac{108}a}=2\cdot6\sqrt3$$  the equality(i.e., the minimum value of $a+b$) occurs if $\displaystyle\sqrt a-\sqrt{\frac{108}a}=0\implies a=\sqrt{108}=6\sqrt3$